# How do I jailbreak my iPhone 4?

Tags: iphone, jailbreak

I'm looking to go rogue. Where do I jailbreak my iPhone 4.

Comment: I'm going to close this for re-work or perhaps re-asking with more specific details so someone can determine if a jailbreak will work for their iPhone 4 on iOS 4 or iOS 5. This question has served it's purpose near the time of iOS 4.0 release, but has grown stale and misleading as currently stated.

Answer (score 5):

Open up Safari on your iPhone 4 and go to jailbreakme.com.
Sit tight for couple minutes and your iPhone is jailbroken. You'll see that Cydia app is installed.

It uses PDF security flaw on mobile Safari. It will be patched soon, so jailbreak now while it's available. It's by far the easiest way to jailbreak your iPhone.

It jailbreaks iOS 4.0.1 which is the latest at the moment.

Edit (8/11/2010): [Apple has just releases iOS 4.0.2](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4291) to fix the PDF exploit that jailbreakme.com uses. Jailbreakme.com should still work for iOS 4.0.1 and below.

Edit (8/13/2010): PDF Patch is available for download in Cydia. Search for "PDF Patch." You can jailbreak 4.0.1 and then just patch PDF bug instead of upgrading to 4.0.2 and wait for jailbreak to be available.

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: Disregard this, it's no longer true. There are jailbreaks - http://jailbreak.me works before 4.0.2, and (apparently) redsn0w works with 4.0.2 on 2G and 3G.

AFAIK, there is no released jailbreak for the iphone4 just yet. The [iPhone Dev Team](http://blog.iphone-dev.org/) is working on it though; they have a jailbreak but haven't released it yet.

I'm sure they will release it when they think it's ready.

Comment: The conventional wisdom is that it'll be released once iOS 4.1 is released (since it's been seeded to developers). No sense releasing it and giving Apple a chance to plug any holes any faster than necessary.

Comment: This answer should be deleted/ignored, as it is no longer true.

Answer (score 0):

You can always check out http://jailbrea.kr