# Jailbreak iPhone for non-US country

Tags: iphone

Am I able to get a new iPhone 4 for non US Country (India). My plan is someone coming from US can bring to one to India. Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 2):

iPhone is being sold without any contract in any western european country that sells them, because they are now required to do so. In fact, Apple itself sells the iPhone 4 without a contract.

In the USA, however, things are [different](http://store.apple.com/us/browse/home/shop_iphone/family/iphone?aid=AIC-WWW-NAUS-K2-BUYNOW-IPHONE-INDEX#faqs), and you have to have a 2 year AT&T contract.

In Spain, the Online Apple Store sells the iPhone completely contract-free, as you can read in [this text (in Spanish)](http://store.apple.com/es/browse/home/shop_iphone/family/iphone#faqs), however they only ship within Spain. I assume other Apple Stores in Europe follow the same practice.

Regarding the Jailbreak, you should read [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/1797/115).

Comment: So if someone from Europe buys an Iphone and ships here does it work

Comment: If they buy it contract-free unlocked factory (directly from Apple), then yes. Individual vendors (Vodafone, Orange, etc.) will sell you the phone at a lower price, but you will have to sign a contract for 2 years and pay them the corresponding data and voice fees.

Comment: @unknownBBUser: Exactly, **if** it is *factory unlocked*, as Martín says. Maybe you could get one from UK with [this advice](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2276/buying-officially-unlocked-iphone-4-in-the-us/2284#2284) I posted to another question.

Answer (score 0):

you must note that Apple produce iPhone in 2 way.

1. Normal Mode that @Martin told above.
2. Unlocked Factory

if you tell your friend(family) that bought you "unlocked factory" iPhone for you yes it work fine for you in India. and if they bought normal iPhone if you jailbreak it, you must able to use it with other simcard.