# iphone unlocked in bestbuy?

Tags: iphone

I am in vancouver B.C. Is the iphone4 bought in bestbuy official unlocked?I saw that the network of iphone4 is telus but have a uncontract price on bb website. So can the iphone4 be used in other countries? thank you!

Comment: related: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2276/buying-officially-unlocked-iphone-4-in-the-us